# AWS Amplify + Graphql + Dynamodb: ConditionalCheckFailedException error on mutation

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

In what has been the least helpful error message of 2021, my `createUser` mutation, despite being passed inputs satisfying all requirements, throws this bummer of a message:

```
data: {createUser: null}
errors: [{path: ["createUser"], data: null, errorType: "ConditionalCheckFailedException", errorInfo: null,…}]
0: {path: ["createUser"], data: null, errorType: "ConditionalCheckFailedException", errorInfo: null,…}
data: null
errorInfo: null
errorType: "ConditionalCheckFailedException"
locations: [{line: 2, column: 3, sourceName: null}]
0: {line: 2, column: 3, sourceName: null}
column: 3
line: 2
sourceName: null
message: "The conditional request failed (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 70BUB7TAU32M7JGGO6324LGR53VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF6ZZ6ZQ9ASUAAJG, Extended Request ID: null)"
path: ["createUser"]
```

My schema:

```
type ScheduledEmail @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  frequency: Frequency!
  scheduleHour: ScheduleHour!
  scheduleStart: ScheduleStart!
  user: [User] @connection(keyName: "byScheduledEmail", fields: ["id"])
}

type User @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) @key(name: "byScheduledEmail", fields: ["scheduledEmailId"]) {
  id: ID!
  email: String!
  subscriptions: [ID]!
  name: String
  scheduledEmailId: ID
  scheduledEmail: ScheduledEmail @connection
}
```

When keys and values have been mismatched, dynamodb has been kind of enough to be specific about it.
I haven't provided it a condition so I'm not sure how it can be failing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was passing to the mutation a unique ID that I needed to generate myself which it apparently doesn't like. Arg.

Answer (score 0):

This is the result I get when a value with the same ID already exists.  It doesn't seem very descriptive but I bet in this example previous unit tests had already created records with those IDs.  Thus removing the ID forced the generation of a new one, thus satisfying the condition that the ID not already exist.